# Ubuntu 15.04 systemctl: command not found

Tags: 15.04, upstart, autostart, systemd

I am currently trying to install Syncthing and have it start automatically.

I am following the guide [Starting Syncthing Automatically - Using systemd](http://docs.syncthing.net/users/autostart.html#using-systemd).

I have a file called "syncthing@myuser.service" saved at /etc/systemd/system. So basically I am trying to achieve autostart by using systemd.

The command to enable it is:

```bsh
systemctl enable syncthing@myuser.service
```

But this gives me the error:

```
sudo: systemctl: command not found
```

From what I know since 15.04 systemd is the replacement for upstart. But why is `systemctl` missing? Can I just install it and hope for the best?

Comment: Place your service in /lib/systemd/system/ and try again

Comment: @abu_bua all these questions about `systemctl` you have edited are fundamentally and inextricably questions about systemd. There is no point to a separate tag about systemctl, at least not in any of the questions you have edited - they're all about systemd, its features and service management.

Comment: @muru On other sites like unix.stackexchange.com, https://serverfault.com, etc. they made a systemctl tag, which they also  use beside systemd. Hence, for continuation I edited these questions. Btw: these sites even don't use a synonym for it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you  sure systemd is installed? It should provide systemctl:

```
$ dpkg-query -S /bin/systemctl
systemd: /bin/systemctl
```

You could also try the full path: `sudo /bin/systemctl enable syncthing@myuser.service`

I'm on 16.04 LTS, which definitely requires systemd, so upgrading might be an idea if you haven't already …